# EventHandler Library with asynchronous, infinite loop and global variable locking

Tags: c#, asynchronous, event-handling, locking

I'm creating a C# library that will implement an EventHandler that notifies it's listeners when the computer network connection changes, it has two states --connected and not connected.

Given my requirements, I believe I need a global variable in my library that stores the "connected" boolean value and a continual loop that constantly checks for internet connection, comparing the result of that check with my global boolean.

Should I do an async loop method with locking around my global boolean? Is there any set design pattern that I could use? Please point me in the right direction as I'm relatively new to asynchronous patterns and design principles, examples would be helpful.

**Note:** I'm also potentially restricted to .NET 4.0, so useful things like Task.Delay might not be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an event handler already exists, for physical network connectivity. See [Event to Detect Network Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457773/i-need-a-event-to-detect-internet-connect-disconnect) (stackoverflow.com)

However, if you would like to do it yourself, or want to check for other conditions (like internet access) you could implement it thus:

```
    public static bool IsConnected { get; protected set; }
    protected readonly static object _sync = new object();
    protected static Task NetworkTask;

    public static void Start(int period = 1000)
    {
        NetworkTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                lock (_sync)
                {
                    IsConnected = MyNetworkManager.IsConnected();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(period);
                }
            });
    }
```

Please note you cannot lock a boolean directly, since it is a value type, but you can create a readonly object to act as a proxy for the lock.

Comment: I have seen the EventHandlers that exist to do this, but I'm tasked with writing my own. Thank you for the implementation though, this is how I envisioned doing it myself.